# remote backup with appcfg.py/bulkloader.py with script. how to handle the email/password fields?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bash

I'm trying to write a script in python or bash which executes bulkloader.py to backup my entities on appengine but I don't know how to handle the email and password prompts on the bulkloader.

is there a way to insert those fields in a bash or python script?

Comment: I didn't quit get the question, but is this what you are looking for? [Here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: yes that works! using the --passin option and a '<< mypwd' thank you

Comment: Welcome! I have also mentioned it as an answer, so that people with similar problem can have their answer.

Comment: Can you please write the entire solution you find? I'm having the same problem and I can't figure out how you solved.. expecially for that "and a'<< mypwd' part.. Did you use -a? --append? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). Available for bash scripts and languages like Perl, PHP, Python, PowerShell and Ruby.